# JSON Unexpected Token - Unfortunately from a not very technical person

Tags: json

Hello fellow colleagues,

I run a e-learning platform on Wordpress with Learndash - WooCommerce - Elementor and Ultimate Member. I also recently installed a Sucuri Firewall.

Lately a lot of my students mentioned that they experience difficulties in checkout. They fill every info in and when the click "complete order" they get an Error "Unexpected token ´<," "... is not valid JSON

As a non-technical person, who has limited Information on this topic, I contacted every one of the plugin customer success agents and proceed with the following steps:

1. increased php time limit and memory
2. enabled debugging

Unfortunately I still experience the issue - since my research didn't bring much. I wanted to ask you, where and what should I look for in order to avoid future conflicts.

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It never hurts to copy the entire error report (unless very long), remove info unique to your site or installation, and Google it. Using the main parts of your question, 'woocommerce checkout unexpected token is not valid json', I got a number of similar reports, though no single fix.

One thing that solved the issue for some users was to re-save permalinks: Go to Admin/Settings/Permalinks, and re-save them - [https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-regenerate-your-permalinks-in-wordpress/#:~:text=To%20regenerate%20your%20permalinks%2C%20just,has%20now%20regenerated%20your%20permalinks](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-regenerate-your-permalinks-in-wordpress/#:%7E:text=To%20regenerate%20your%20permalinks%2C%20just,has%20now%20regenerated%20your%20permalinks).

If that fixes it, then you'll probably call that good enough, and not try to find out why it started happening.

If that doesn't work, and you don't find an error report that clearly duplicates yours, you might try this post, which is from 2015, but still useful (and educational!). https://mikejolley.com/2015/11/12/debugging-unexpected-token-in-woocommerce-2-4/

You can also try again providing the full error statement.

Good luck!

Comment: Hello There,

Hello there, thank you very much for your comment. 

I checked the permalinks and regenerated them. I also deactivated Limit Login Attempts Reloaded plug in - helped one student to proceed with the checkout. However another one still experiences: String did not match the expected array problem. – 


I checked the debug.log and at the time of the error we get the following message: 

Notice: Function wpdb::prepare was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Unsupported value type (array). And more lines specifying the issue - but I don't have anymore characters left to copy.

Comment: Well, you might need to retreat to the basic troubleshooting stand-by of disabling plugins, one by one if necessary, and switching to a basic WordPress "annual" theme until you can isolate the cause of the underlying issue. As for including more content of error messages, you can edit your original question.